# Allowing Apache in Ubuntu to access files in NTFS hard drive

Tags: apache-2.2, ntfs

I have LAMP running in Ubuntu.

However, my files are located on a separate NTFS hard drive (/media/shared/mysite/).

going to http://localhost gives me a 403

how can i, securely, allow apache to read/write the NTFS disk?

'shared' is currently being mounted when system boots. here's the entry in fstab:

```
/dev/sda1       /media/shared    ntfs-3g    quiet,defaults,locale=en_US.utf8,umask=000     0      0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the permissions of the files there?
Try a ls -l /media/shared

Comment: drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 2009-11-04 22:02 websites

Comment: Check if the share is mounted RO or RW
#mount
If it's RW, make:
# su - www-data
# cd /media/shared
# touch test.test
# ls -l test*
and see what's happen

Comment: RW. doing what you say, shows everything is owned by root. for example, here's a line from the output: "-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   85 2009-06-30 06:19 del.php"

Comment: So you can create any file you want with www-data user in that dir?
If yes...what apache logs say?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [14/May/2010:12:45:41 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 496 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.9 Safari/533.2"

Comment: I was also able to create files and dirs as www-data user

Comment: I mean about the logs, when you try to access to your web server and you get error 403, what the logs say?

Comment: error log is blank. access log: "127.0.0.1 - - [14/May/2010:12:45:41 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 496 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.9 Safari/533.2"

Answer (score 2):

After many many attempts here is what succeeded for me that is : changing the configuration of Apache so that it uses « www-data » (Apache user) no more but my own user instead.

Very simple to do. In my version of Apache the two lines to be changed are in the « /etc/apache2/envvars » file (it can be another file in another version) :

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

I replaced « www-data » by my user name (here « toto » :)) :

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=toto
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=toto
```